# Alert for February 2013 "Authenticated referrals going away "

Tags: facebook

My app allows users to sign in using Facebook.

I do it so I have access to the user's name, address etc as they've recorded in their Facebook accounts.

I don't think this has anything to do wht "Authenticated referrals" or anything else described in the list of changes happening in Feb 2013 but just want to double check this is correct.

Can anyone comment?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that's correct. you don't use authenticated referrals at all :)